# weird characters in Chinese

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In browser, it's showing something like below:

[image]

when I inspect it in developer console, it is showing normal:

[image: enter link description here]

so, it looks like the colon is a not being improperly encoded.

The problem is that I don't have control of the content, the information is retrieved from somewhere else using ajax call and I use jQuery to retrieve city information.

```
var toCity = $(infoOutHtml).find('#HeaderDes').text();
```

when I `console.log(toCity)`  it shows normal in console:   `目 的 地：中国`

but when I render it to html, it become weird:

```
var Information = "<div id=\"trackingNum\" class=\"spacer-banner blueFontWhiteBg\">"+
     "<span  id=\"transit-id\">"+toCity +"</span>"+
"</div>"

$($info).html(information);
```

I am just wondering what's the problem here? how to ignore the colon before render it to html?

I tried this, but doesn't work at all:

```
function somefunction(string){

  return string.replace(/:/,'\\\\:');

}

toCity = somefunction(toCity);
```

Comment: What is the font your are using for displaying the text on the website ? Your font probably don't have the ':' character and has this symbol in its place.

Comment: JavaScript will not get the HTML entity version of the `.text()`. If you can View Source then you might be able to see what the problem is. Of course, that won't work if you're using JavaScript to generate the HTML. Use the HTML entity for colon `&#058;`.

Comment: @krtek, you are right. the font don't have ":"   I changed font family and it shows right now.

Comment: @JavaScripter maybe you could add that as an answer and accept it to clearly mark this question as resolved. Others may found the answer useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@krtek is right, I used the font family which doesn't have ":".

Comment: If the primary font does not have “：”, then the browser takes “：” from another font. Check out whether your primary font had a wrong glyph for “：”. And make sure you check U+FF1A FULLWIDTH COLON, because that’s what “：” in the data is.